# LWJGL won't work with a bytebuffer but will work with a float array

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I'm trying to display a texture through LWJGL:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureId);

            BufferedImage img = null;

            img = ImageIO.read(new File(filePath));

            Raster imgRaster = img.getData();

            DataBufferByte imgBuffer = (DataBufferByte) imgRaster.getDataBuffer();

            ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(imgBuffer.getData());

            //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1,1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, new float[]{1f,0f,1f});
            glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), 0,
                         GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, byteBuffer);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
            glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
```

However, the texture is completely black (no errors as far as I can tell). In the debugger, I verified that there is indeed data in the bytebuffer (enough to account for a texture of the size I provided), so I should at least see something.

However, if I quickly throw a few floats in an array and pass it to glTexImage2D:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, 1,1, 0, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, new float[]{1f,0f,1f});
```

The shape on the screen suddenly turns magenta.

I've had trouble with those *Buffers in the past,and replacing them with arrays always seemed to work.

Do I need to do something with the ByteBuffer to make it work?

Comment: After you put the data in the ByteBuffer, have tried flipping the buffer to reset it back to be readable?  Another question, are you sure the data type of the DataBuffer you're retrieving from the Raster is 3 byte RGB format?

Comment: I assume you mean `byteBuffer.flip()` (just after the call to wrap())? Didn't seem to help. Also, if I use the wrong format, I should at least see something, right? Not just a black square?

Comment: Not sure if the is optimal, but when I load images via BufferedImage,  I first create an int[] array of the width*height of the image then read using img.getRGB(0,0,width,height,data,0,width).  Then, because the images I load are in ARGB format I move the alpha byte to the end making it RGBA.  I then create a ByteBuffer of width * height * 4 size, set the ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN, then do buffer.asIntBuffer().put(data).  Lastly I do a buffer.flip().  I create the image with glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, width,height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

Comment: That's really ugly, buf sort of what I ended up doing. I just iterated over all x/y coordinates and changed into an an array of a type that LWJGL accepts directly. Still, I don't see why the ByteByffer just won't work.